# Weather maps api's

Tags: api, weather, noaa

I would like to produce some global weather maps. Air temperatures, wind speeds, ocean swells etc

I know I can download the GRIB files and interpret them directly from NOAA. However this is quite resource intensive for my needs!

Do you know of any other weather map api's aside from Openweathermap.org?
(https://openweathermap.org/api)

Answer (score 1):

[api.weather.gov](https://api.weather.gov/) is great and in my opinion, incredibly easy to use.
[API Web Services](https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api) has all the information you'll need to get up and running.